# Unable to run a Aurelia Standalone app without node server

Tags: apache, aurelia

I tried to build a project with Aurelia app with au CLI like au build --env prod then I copied the scripts and index.html to a new directory on my local server which I tried to open up in chrome like Bundled Angular project but I get  error like this '**XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost/aureliafp/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?filter[name]=home-pa‌​ge. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null'; that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**' I do not know what is causing this. So please help me out if you have ran into this error before.

Comment: It sounds like you have a request going to a server that doesn't exist on the same one you're running on. If you were running everything on local host earlier, and now are running on a different site, any requests to something other than the site you're running on will provide you with this error.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew I solved the issue. It was so silly of me to opening the index.htm directly from file browser instead of going through internet browser now everything works perfectly.

Comment: glad you got it working. Feel free to post an answer of what you did, and then mark that answer as what solved your problem, that way others can easily see how to solve the same issue.